# how remove titlebar using FragmentActivity in android?

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

im using API lv 9 so i cant use FragmentBreadCrumbs rquire api lvl11 to hide titlebar,

what should i do because in normal activity hiding titlebar is simply

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
```

but in FragmentActivity how should i hide the TitleBar using api 9 only?

Comment: it does not work in fragment activity??

Comment: yup it does not work. And im only using API 9. I dont know what api should i use, the FragmentBreadCrumbs is api 11 that can hide titlebar in FragmentActivity, but i want to use only API 9.

Comment: what support library are you using for fragments??

Comment: im using v4 suport library not v7 appcompat, i want to try without using v7 appcompat. How can i do it using v4 library and using only api 9.

Answer (score 0):

in `onCreate` try:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: im using api 9 and also im not using v7 appcompat.

getSupportActionBar() not aplicable because ned v7 appcompat

getActionBar() needs api 11 but im using only api9